# Daily XML Parsing in ASP.NET MVC Application

Tags: design-patterns, asp.net-mvc-4, architecture, entity-framework-4, xml-parsing

I have an ASP.NET MVC4 application that uses Entity Framework for its Domain Model, that *Domain model sits in its own project within the same solution*. For populating its Database store, the web application is dependant on an XML file that gets generated once a day.

I have a couple of questions. One is related to the best architectural approach in terms of code placement and system design.

1. Where should my Parsing code go for Parsing the XML document and storing the parsed data into the EF database? I know I can place it pretty much everywhere, but in terms of best software practice, where would it go best? My idea at the moment is to create a class (XMLParser) in the Domain project.
2. How can I get my XML Parser (where ever I've decided to place it) to **run once a day** at a particular time?

Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I think the domain is not the best place for an XML parser. The Domain is, as its name suggests, there to represents the entities and terms of your *business domain*.
   Classes such as `User`, `Order` etc. will go in there. an XML parser is **not** a part of your business domain.
   Where should that parser go, then? Let's think what it's job is- it reads data from some data store and transforms it into domain classes.
   After representing the issue in such a way, I think the solution is obvious- a class which is responsible for retrieving data from a data store (be it database, file or web service) belongs in the data access layer.
2. There are a couple of solutions. [Quartz.NET](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/) is a scheduling mechanism for the .net platform with a lot of advanced scheduling capabilities.
   However, if you're just looking to execute something once a day, [windows' scheduled tasks](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308569) could be enough

Comment: Thank You SJohnny. I don't have a fully decoupled data access layer. So would that mean I simply put the parsing code in an Action on one my MVC Controllers? Also, if the parsing code isn't a separate application, can Window's scheduled tasks run a specific Action on a specific Controller once a day?

Comment: the answer to your second question is 'no', so therefore my answer to your first question would be to create a dedicated project for the xml parsing, with an executable as the project output, so that it could be run by the scheduler

Comment: I shall do that then. I shall create a separate executable project dedicated to the parsing and saving functionality. Thanks sJohnny. :)